# The site goes to the right DNS without www

Tags: apache2, amazon-ec2

I have a website hosted with ec2 at http://tanish-bilish.com. We got the DNS from network solutions.

My apache 2 config looks like this

```
ServerName tanish-bilish.com
ServerAlias www.wanish-bilish.com
```

My DNS settings look like this

```
* (All Others)    7200  184.73.125.64
@ (None)              7200  184.73.125.64
www.tanishbilish.com  7200  184.73.125.64
```

For some reason http://www.tanish-bilish.com goes to some place else. Could some one help me with what could it be.

Answer (score 1):

Is it supposed to have a hyphen or not - the URL you give does not match the DNS entry

and is it Tanish or Wanish? because your first entry doesn't match either.

Comment: it is suppose to have that hyphen.

Comment: are you saying your example is wrong or your DNS is wrong - if your example is wrong I would suggest you EDIT it.

Comment: @Jinesh Parekh, cut-and-paste from actual server configuration or code beats re-typing it every single time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Strangely it works fine if I switched the servername and server alias like below

```
ServerName www.tanish-bilish.com
ServerAlias wanish-bilish.com
```

Comment: Note though that this is *not* equivalent to your original example.